# CakePHP 2.3 mod_rewrite not working

Tags: apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite

i have a Problem, written a Webapp in CakePHP 1.3 and it worked fine, so i wanted to use the newer cake version and after copying it on my local Apache (which might have the correct configuration until the older Cake runs fine) it displays the Error that mod_rewrite isn't working. So i dont get it, because if i compare the .htaccess of both cake-versions there are many differences, so i tried to use the old .htaccess for the newer cake 2.3 but got the Error 500.

So i really dont get the issue, because the Apache is definately configured correctly.

Here's what my .htaccess files (cake 2.3.1) contains:

cake/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

cake/app/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

cake/app/webroot/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: that is the wrong htaccess file, the right one is in /webroot directly

Comment: oh sure sorry, so i added the missing .htaccess-files

Comment: where do you get this last webroot htaccess file? please take a look at the core files (publically accessable via github for example) and compare then. then you will find out that yours is indeed invalid.

Comment: well this seems to be correct, doesn't it?
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.1/app/webroot/.htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My webroot htaccess looks like

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

and works just fine with 2.x

But the recommended way would be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

as you lined out. That should work in all systems.

see [webroot htaccess](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.3.1/lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/webroot/.htaccess)

Also make sure that mod_rewrite is not just available but allowed to be enabled via htaccess.
You will need sth like "AllowOverride All" in your virtual host / config setting.
Not everywhere this is the default.

Comment: Okay, doesn't matter which one i take, it still says:
"URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server."

So usually at this point i'd think that the issue is located in the apache-conf, but all other cake projects i run on the server (1.x) are running as expected.

Comment: I'm using PHP v. 5.3.8. so PDO is installed by default and phpinfo(); tells me that mod_rewrite module is loaded, so i am not sure if the cake-error message is true, is there any way to check it manually?

Comment: AllowOverride All has already been set, well actually it seems to be working and just the error-message was falsely displayed